# Word problem in linear equation

Tags: combinatorics

I just can't figure it out how to solve this one.The problem is as follows:

> Of 28 students taking at least one subject, the number taking Math and
>   English but not History equals the number taking Math but not History
>   or  English. No student takes English only or History only, and six
>   students take  Math and History but not English. The number taking
>   English and History but  not Math is 5 times the number taking all
>   three subjects. If the number taking  all three subjects is even and
>   non-zero, how many are taking English and Math  but not History?

Comment: Are you familiar with Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion (PIE) ?

Comment: Nah i haven't studied combinatorial mathematics much

Comment: Take a look at [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). PIE is useful in solving problems of this type. And as grdgfgr pointed out, always use a Venn diagram if you get confused with problems like this. Visualizing the problem using Venn diagrams helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Draw a Venn diagram and fill the information in.